# How many views does the ListView can hold for reuse?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapterview

I have a `ListView` contains about 15 items on one screen, and the items in the full `ListView` are of 10 kinds, if I scroll the `ListView` up and down, I can find some type of items' `convertView` are null.

What I want to know whether there is a limit of the size or amount of the views that recycled for reuse? What can I do to avoid the recycled view become null?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats wrong with null `convertView`s? you cannot "feed" your `ListView` with the views in advance so couple of first calls to `getView` has to have null `convertView`

Comment: if recycled view is null, i think that means a new item was infilated, for reasons i am not aware of, it's something decided by the adapter i think. but AFAIK , as long as you are implementing a reuse approach, there is nothing more u can do

Comment: The kind or requirement you are having, I would suggest to switch to RecycleView. Any number of views and any type of views are handled efficiently in recycleview

Comment: @pskink It's not the first call, the same kind has more than one that recycled(that is invisible), but why it would null rather than reuse the recycled ones.

Comment: If you have 15 items on the screen you dont have much more convertviews laying around. it wont keep view simply because you might use it. It keeps them because they are on the screen

Comment: @MohammedAtif RecycleView is not so fit for our business.

Comment: @Yazan What about main my own cache?

Comment: Also RecycleView is better than ListView in every aspect, its just a bit more difficult to setup it.

Comment: if it is null it means that list view does not have any recycled view to use and ask you to create a new one

Comment: trust me, you don't want to go that way, interfering adapter behavior and so, can really get you in some trouble, unexpected behavior, bugs, ...etc it's better to stick to standard approach, but if your items has some kind of resources, you can cache them, like (images, database records, shapes... etc) but i recommend that you stay at safe side.

Comment: @twlkyao , no offense but, I dont understand how ReyclerView can effect your business in Negative way. I know only the advantages of RecyclerView for simple as well as complex tasks, Someone mentioned about setting up reyclerview is difficult, trust me, set it up twice, you will never think about list view again. For more details you can refer my blog - http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/

Comment: @MohammedAtif Thanks, I will advice my team change to RecycleView.